# How to add Identity Provider in AWS SAM or Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-sam

I'm trying yo add an identity provider like described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpoolidentityprovider.html#cfn-cognito-userpoolidentityprovider-attributemapping) in my SAM application .

When I run `sam deploy` I get the following error:

```
The attribute mapping is missing required attributes [nickname] (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: xy; Proxy: null)
```

Although in my YAML definition I mapped the attribute `nickname` as follows:

```
UserPoolIdentityProvider:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolIdentityProvider
    Properties: 
      AttributeMapping:
        given_name: "nickname"
        sub: "username"
        email: "email"
      ProviderDetails:
        ...
```

Comment: Does your user pool has nickname required? When you do the mapping, check what is required from your user pool and what are your provider fields.

Comment: Yes nickname is a required attribute in my userpool. I checkt the attributes from the provider. I actually tested the whole thing before using the aws console. There I mapped the given_name to nickname as well and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if provider has "nickname" attribute and if pool supports that.

Comment: no the provider does not have 'nickname' as attribute. That is the aws attribute I want to map to. So I just realized that I mixed up the keys and values from the Mapping. I should be the other way around. So the correct way of specifying the mapping here is: nickname: "given_name". Just tried it and it worked.